# Why is the meaning of人一倍 opposite of what it seems to say?

Tags: words, etymology

This could be just me, but at first glance the word (phrase?) 人一倍【ひといちばい】 looks like it would mean "one's own share of the work". I assumed 人 to mean one person, and 一倍【いちばい】 means "one share, one amount". I was a little confused to find out that 人一倍 actually means "more than others, redoubled, unusual". (For example, 人一倍働く【ひといちばいはたら】 means " to work twice as hard as others".)

Does anyone have any insight or explanation for this, or have I completely misunderstood the whole thing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [大辞林](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E4%B8%80%E5%80%8D&stype=0&dtype=0&dname=0ss), one of the meanings of 一倍 is as follows:

> ある数量を二つ合わせた数量。二倍。倍。

The first example it gives includes `人一倍`, so you're right that `人一倍` is the combination of `人` and `一倍`.  The surprising part is that `一倍` means `二倍`!

As [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%80%8D) explains, for much of the history of Japan, `倍` was a suffix indicating a number of times *in addition* to one.  In other words, `一倍`, `二倍`, and `三倍` used to mean 2x, 3x, and 4x.  In modern Japanese, they generally mean 1x, 2x, and 3x, but as you've discovered, the old meaning of `倍` is not entirely gone--it's preserved in words like `人一倍`.

You may also want to read the answers on this [similar question in Japanese](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/1230733.html).

Comment: The old meaning is still preserved in Chinese, where the old and new meanings entirely are dependent on context. "A is 一倍 of B" = A=2B, "A is 二倍 the size of B" = A=2B as well ;)

Answer (score 3):

Snailplane-san is right.  In Yedo era there were two words indicating multiple number: 倍 and [層倍]{そうばい}.  A single word 倍 means two times and a single word 層倍 does one time.  2倍 means 3 times and 2層倍 is two times.

In Meiji era there comes European mathematics and the above-mentioned way to use of 倍 and 層倍 was banned.

Today we use 2倍 as two times.  3倍 means three times.  But the old way to use of 倍 remains in some phrases, such as [倍]{ばい}にして[返]{かえ}す, [倍返]{ばいがえ}し and [人]{ひと}の[倍]{ばい}[働]{はたら}く.  Most of us have never heard of the word 層倍.

Just like you, many Japanese wonder about [人一倍]{ひといちばい}.  I must study English with sense of language like you.  Good luck for your studying Japanese!

Answer (score 2):

snailplane is right about her explanation. 
Not sure about Nihongo but in Mandarin, the confusing one is `一倍` and `二倍` is used interchangeably. Meaning might be different at different context. So just read carefully.